# What's best practice in Spring Data JPA Error handling

Tags: java, spring, jpa, exception

I'm new in the world of spring and Spring Data.

I've build a user- and permission management system where a user can grant and remove permissions for another user.

I've digged in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) but I'm not shure how to handle querys where I just want to insert or manipulate Data in a Table.

In the docs query return type table I couldn't find something like a status or a status reporting object.

What I'm looking for is a pattern that allows me to controle is an operation was successfull. Right now I'm using primitives. When everything worked out I get "1" returned but when I query an empty table I get "0". So I need something with more details.

Thank you for guidance and sharing your experience.

**EDIT:**
Here is a code example:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM permissions WHERE producerId=:producerId AND comsumerId=:consumerId", nativeQuery = true)
void clearAllPermissions(@Param("producerId") Long producerId,@Param("consumerId") Long consumerId);
```

The Method is provided by my repository class.

```
    @Repository
    public interface PermissionsRepository extends JpaRepository<ProducerConsumerPermissions, Integer>{
.
.
.
}
```

I call the class from my service layer which is used by my Controller layer.
I guess it'd be nice to know if this operation was successfull so that I can transport the exeption throught the layer till my frontend and throw a message to the user. But when the Table is empty I get a value of false back when I use Integer as return type.

Comment: This is imho a primarily opinion-based question :/

Comment: in Java error handling is usually done using exceptions, not control codes

Comment: I think you are mixing multiple issues at once. Spring repositories allow the return type `boolean` for `existsBy...`-methods for checking the existence of entities found by e.g. ID.

Comment: Can you post some of your code to see who you did it right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your method return `int` then you know if any records are deleted.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM permissions WHERE producerId=:producerId AND comsumerId=:consumerId", nativeQuery = true)
int clearAllPermissions(@Param("producerId") Long producerId,@Param("consumerId") Long consumerId);
```

If there is a problem it will throw and exception anyway. Spring Data throws `DataAccessException` that you can catch to see what went wrong.

Comment: yes that was my first thought how to solve this. So I check the return value. If it is 0 it means no rows have been affected. So I make another query to make shure that there is no related data left in the database before I return true.

Comment: Why do you think that you have to make a second query? And 0 is not a return value that's number of affected records

Comment: It is very sensitive data and the operation has to be successfull. So I was thinking about a second checking mechanism but I guess your solution should be save enough.

Comment: The database will not give you another result the second time. That's why we use Databases they have transactions and guarantee ACID

Comment: If my answer solved your problem I would appreciate if you mark it as the correct answer. Thank you